# javascript removechild and remove not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to generate a row dynamically. It's generating but, I'm not able to remove the row....

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
            function Clonediv(divid) {
                var application_id = $('#app_id').val();
                //var rn = $('#rownum').val;
// var i = 0;
                //alert(rn);
                var rownum;
                if (application_id != "") {
                    var cloned = $('#hdnClonedrows').val();
                    var num = parseInt(cloned);
                    num = num + 1;
                    i = i + 1;
                    $('#hdnClonedrows').val(num);
                    clonedelement = num;
                    rownum = "Requirement" + i;
                    // alert(rownum);
                    var newtr = document.createElement('tbody');
                    newtr.id = "Clonedrow_" + clonedelement;
                    $('#tableroles1').append(newtr);
                    $('#rowtoclone').css("display", "block");
                    var abc = $('#rowtoclone').clone();
                    $('#rowtoclone').css("display", "none");
                    abc.appendTo(newtr);
                }
                else {
                    alert("Please select an application to add a Requirement");
                    //$('#errordiv').html('Please select an application to add a Requirement<br/><br/>');
                }
            }
            $("#remove").on("click", ".removebutton", function (e) {
                //e.preventDefault();
                //e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                e.removeChild(tableroles1);
                $(this).parents("newtr").remove();
            });
                </script>
```

```html
<html>
    
    <a id="Adddiv" class="clAddNewLeft" href="javascript:Clonediv();">Add Requirements</a><br />
                @{
                    string rowid = "Clonedrow_" + @clonedelement;
                    int rownum = 1;
                        //rownum = rownum + 1;
          
                    <div id = '@rowid'>
    
                        <table id="tableroles1">
    
                            <tr id="rowtoclone" style="display: none">
    
                                <td>
                                    <label id="rownum">Requirement @rownum  </label>
    
                                </td>
    
                                <td class="editValue">
                                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.requirements, new { @class = "updatable", @style = "height : 150px; width : 653px" })
    
                                </td>
                                <td class="editValue">
                                    @using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                                    {
                                        <input type="file" name="file" id="fileToUpload" />
                                        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="upload" />
                                    }
    
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <img alt="delete" src="../../Images/deleteIcon4.gif" id="remove" style="cursor: pointer;" />
                                </td>
    
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                }
    

    
    
    
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using `.removeChild()` on something that is really a parent. If you're trying to remove the `"tableroles1"` table, try to use this for your delete function:

```
$("#remove").on("click", function (e) {

    $("#tableroles1").remove();

});
```

This should do the following:

1) When the user clicks on the delete image it calls the function above

2) We then target 3 parent nodes above the image tag, which is `<table id="tableroles1">`

3) We then remove that parent which will remove all of the child elements as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help. now dynamically row is generating but, if I delete middle row, it should not delete. the end row only allow to delete....help me

Comment: @km6 I just updated the answer. Instead of using ```parent()```, just target the actual element of ```$("#tableroles1")```